what is the kube-prometheus-stack (helm-chart) compatible version for eks 1.29?
I am looking to upgrade my eks from 1.27 to 1.29. So  I would like to know the compatible version of kube-prometheus-stack helm chart. Please provide me the link or help me in suggesting the version.

You can refer to this table; as kubernetes prometheus stack uses prometheus operator to configure monitoring. This approach helps warrant the compatibility of Prometheues & the related components in the charts (eg. Grafana etc).
Base on the table and for your case of >1.27; which is the main branch; you should use the latest version of kube-prometheus-stack.

Thanks for the update. I have already seen this, but based on this table, how can i choose the appropriate version of kube-prometheus-stack. i am not able to identify that part. can you please help which version of kube-prometheus-stack should i choose based on this prometheus-operator table

Answer updated for >1.27
